# Error when working on project from windows 10 laptop

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Good morning, I have a rather large project that I've been working on without any problems on my mac desktop, but I'm having a problem preventing me from building anything when I attempt to work on the project from a windows machine.

My shared project contains code like:

```
 if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
{

        // Create base Alert Controller
        UIAlertController alertController = UIAlertController.Create("", null, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
...
```

Which needs a reference to Xamarin.iOS, but when attempting to add that reference under a clean install, I get an error

> "'CSHarpAddImportCodeFixProvider' has encountered an error and has
>   been disabled"
>
> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. ---> Unable
>   to find a type of reference that is appropriate for this file:
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\Xamarin.iOS.dll".

Anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by replacing those statements with

```
    #if __IOS__
 #endif 
...
    #if__ANDROID__ 
...
#endif
```

and then removing the IOS macro from the args, which causes the statement to act as a comment, and allows me to work on and build the android app on my PC, while ignoring the iOS specific code.

Not sure if it's exactly a smart method, but no problems so far.